# Visit count in MCTS search keeps being zero

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, monte-carlo-tree-search

I am coding a AI project that involves a MCTS search. After each iteration the search is supposed to backpropagate the data back and increase the visit_count of each parent also by 1, which is in this function here:

```
def backpropagate(self, value):
    self.value_sum += value
    self.visit_count += 1
        
    value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
    if self.parent is not None:
        self.parent.backpropagate(value)
```

The function is being called here in the search():

```
@torch.no_grad()
def search(self, state):
    print(type(state))
    root = Node(self.game, self.args, state, visit_count=1)
    
    policy, _ = self.model(
        torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
    )

    policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
    policy = (1 - self.args['dirichlet_epsilon']) * policy + self.args['dirichlet_epsilon'] \
        * np.random.dirichlet([self.args['dirichlet_alpha']] * self.game.action_size)
    
    valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(state)
    policy *= valid_moves
    policy /= np.sum(policy)
    root.expand(policy)
    
    for search in range(self.args['num_searches']):
        node = root
        
        while node.is_fully_expanded():
            node = node.select()
            
        value, is_terminal = self.game.get_value_and_terminated(node.state, node.action_taken)
        value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
        
        if not is_terminal:
            policy, value = self.model(
                torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(node.state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
            )
            policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
            valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(node.state)
            # print(policy) if random.randint(1, 100) == 100 else print(None)
            policy *= valid_moves
            policy /= np.sum(policy)
            
            value = value.item()
            
            node.expand(policy)
            
        node.backpropagate(value)    
        
        
    action_probs = np.zeros(self.game.action_size)
    for child in root.children:
        action_probs[child.action_taken] = child.visit_count
    action_probs /= np.sum(action_probs)
    return action_probs
```

However, when the code runs the visit counts for all but one child of the root node is always zero.

Can anyone help? This problem has been persisting for a long time and I can't seem to find a solution.

I tried checking the visit_count in the backpropagate function when the grandparent == None (parent is root node), and it returned some valid values for visit_count, but it always disappears after

```
def backpropagate(self, value):
    self.value_sum += value
    self.visit_count += 1
    # print(self.parent.visit_count) if self.parent is not None and self.parent.parent is not None else print(None)
    
    value = -value
    if self.parent is not None:
        if self.parent.parent is None:
            print(self.visit_count)
        self.parent.backpropagate(value)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example.  It is quite difficult, if not impossible, to determine the issue (at least for me) without knowing 1) what the sample looks like, 2) what ```Node``` is.   I think it would be easier if you included some debug statements to track the values and how the nodes are traversed as well as making sure those node traversals are actually doing what you're think they are doing.   Particularly the ```while node.is_fully_expanded()``` loop.